# laravel collections merging and combining with two different data sets

Tags: php, laravel

how do I merge a collection if the number items in the collection are not equal? I tried mapping, merging, etc. It's not getting the results I want.
$vitals = $animal->getLatestVitals();

```
    // Get the conditions based on the animal's vitals
    if($vitals)
    {
        $vitalIds = $vitals->pluck('vital_id', 'value')->toArray();

        $conditionVitals = DB::table('condition_vital')
            ->whereIn('vital_id', $vitalIds)->get();

        $collections = $conditionVitals->merge($vitals);


        dd($collections);
        $filtered = $collections->filter(function ($value, $key) {
            if($value->value){
                return $value;
            }
        });

    Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1704 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => {#1698 ▼
      +"condition_id": 51
      +"vital_id": 2
      +"min": "6"
      +"max": "9"
    }
    1 => {#1753 ▼
      +"condition_id": 95
      +"vital_id": 3
      +"min": "3"
      +"max": "4"
    }
    2 => {#1748 ▼
      +"id": "anim_1656735049BzJoGENzpBfip43"
      +"name": "weight"
      +"value": "80"
      +"created_at": "2022-08-14 00:00:00"
      +"animal_id": "ani_1656730205DMhSBgby671VEdazd"
      +"vital_id": 1
    }
    3 => {#1747 ▼
      +"id": "anim_1656735049oDpMUQ5PJkKdVS8ddd"
      +"name": "body_score"
      +"value": "8"
      +"created_at": "2022-07-14 00:00:00"
      +"animal_id": "ani_1656730205DMhSBgby671VEdazd"
      +"vital_id": 2
    }
    4 => {#1744 ▼
      +"id": "anim_1656739859JliRP0IawXz987J"
      +"name": "dental_score"
      +"value": "2"
      +"created_at": "2022-09-01 00:00:00"
      +"animal_id": "ani_1656730205DMhSBgby671VEdazd"
      +"vital_id": 3
    }
 
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

I've merged the collections, now I need them to combine the the array if the vital ID matches and with the min/max values. Something like this:
I don't need any items that doesn't contain the min and max value--but I do need it to merge together.

```
   Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1704 ▼
      #items: array:7 [▼
  
        1 => {#1747 ▼
          +"id": "anim_1656735049oDpMUQ5PJkKdVS8ddd"
          +"name": "body_score"
          +"value": "8"
          +"created_at": "2022-07-14 00:00:00"
          +"animal_id": "ani_1656730205DMhSBgby671VEdazd"
         +"condition_id": 51
          +"vital_id": 2
          +"min": "6"
          +"max": "9"
        }
        2 => {#1744 ▼
          +"id": "anim_1656739859JliRP0IawXz987J"
          +"name": "dental_score"
          +"value": "2"
          +"created_at": "2022-09-01 00:00:00"
          +"animal_id": "ani_1656730205DMhSBgby671VEdazd"
          +"condition_id": 95
          +"vital_id": 3
          +"min": "3"
          +"max": "4"
        }
        }
     
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to combine them in first place, you can achieve this by creating a relation in model and then calling it in query builder, assuming you have a model for Condition Vitals, you can do something like this:

`ConditionVitals.php` Model

```
function vital(){
    return $this->hasOne(Vital::class);
}
```

and then call this relation on your query using `with()` function like this:

```
ConditionVitals::whereIn('vital_id', $vitalIds)->with('vital')->get();
```

what this will do is give you a nice and clean collection like this:

```
{
  "id": "anim_1656735049BzJoGENzpBfip43"
  "name": "weight"
  "value": "80"
  "created_at": "2022-08-14 00:00:00"
  "animal_id": "ani_1656730205DMhSBgby671VEdazd"
  "vital_id": 1
  "vital:{
     "condition_id": 51
     "vital_id": 1
     "min": "6"
     "max": "9"
    }
}
```

This way only those records will be fetched that are required instead of the whole table with non matching IDs. The similar way you can create `belongsTo()` relationship. But make sure those IDs are constrained to avoid any kind of exceptions since the relation won't work otherwise. Get help [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Ah. that is brilliant. Thank you. It is much cleaner than my solution. I just did a bunch of joins

Comment: We all are that person from time to time. Keep learning.